# ASP.NET: "parseerror" error in widget

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We have a widget that can be nested in some page. In the widget we use an MVC controller from which we call the web service in the following way:

```
public JsonpResult GetAllCities()
{
    List<string> allCities = MobileServiceClient.GetAllCities().ToList();
    return Jsonp(allCities);
}
```

As you can see we return JsonpResult.

The service looks as following:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<string> GetAllCities()
{
    var connection = ConnectionManager.Instance.CreateConnection();
    var sql = string.Format("select distinct CityName from V_Cashdesk where CityName is not null");
    var table = DB.GetSQLCached(sql, connection, 5);
    var lstCities = new List<string>();
    if (table != null)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < table.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (table.Rows[i]["CityName"].ToString() != "")
            {
                lstCities.Add(table.Rows[i]["CityName"].ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    return lstCities;
}
```

But, when we call controller's GetAllCities method, "parseerror" comes up in dialog.

The error is:

```
Failed to load resource: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'site_name' is therefore not allowed access.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load site_name/widget/Search/GetAllCities. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'site_name' is therefore not allowed access.
```

How can we get rid of this?

Comment: So you are calling the JSON from a different domain? In this case you need to [enable cors](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

Comment: What if you try `return Jsonp(allcities, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)`?